# Can prove or disprove $\ln{(1+\frac{1}{n})}<n!(e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}})$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, power-series

As the title says, I want to know whether the following inequality is correct.
$$
\ln{(1+\frac{1}{n})}<n!(e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}),  \ \ \forall{n\in\mathbb{N^{+}}}
$$
This inspiration comes from these two similar inequalities:
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} < n!(e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}})< \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{1}{n+1} <\ln{(1+\frac{1}{n})} < \frac{1}{n}
$$
And it has been initially verified by Mathematica (the accuracy is set to 3000 decimal places)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I denote

$$ k(n) := n! \left(e- \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \right) = \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2) }+... $$

Taking exponential from both sides, we have

$$ 1+ \frac{1}{n} < e^{k(n)} = 1+ k(n) +\frac{k(n)^2}{2!} + ... $$

So it suffices to prove  $k(n) + \frac{k(n)^2}{2} >  \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)^2} > \frac{1}{n} $. The latter is equivalent to

$$ n^2 -2n -4 >0, $$

which is satisfied for $n \geq 4$, we need to check only $n = 1,2,3$ but you already did it.

Comment: So Great! This really solved my problem. I didn't expect Taylor expansion to be so simple and effective for this problem.

Comment: @Anwenhu Glad that it is helpful for you :)